# Async Thread Deadlock in Julia When Used With PyCall

Tags: python, multithreading, julia

I'm trying to implement a basic client-server socket structure using Python and Julia, where the producer is in Python and the consumer is in Julia.

My code on the Python side looks like this:

```
def startServer(host='127.0.0.1', port=4002):
  connected = False
  s = socket.socket()
  s.bind((host, port))
  s.listen(5)
  scon, addr = s.accept()
  print 'Got connection from', addr
  return scon, addr
```

On the Julia side, it looks like this:

```
using PyCall

@pyimport server as sdlib

@async begin
  sleep(10)
  print("In the async thread\n")
  s,a = sdlib.startServer("127.0.0.1",4002)
  print("Server started\n")
end

print("After the async thread\n")
print("Connecting...\n")
connected = false
while !connected
  try
    connected = true
    c = connect(4002)
    print("Connected = $(connected), $(c)\n")
  catch ex
    print("$(ex)\n")
    connected = false
    sleep(1)
  end
end
print("Connection established: $(c)\n")
```

The output looks like this:

```
After the async thread
Connecting...
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
connect: connection refused (ECONNREFUSED)
In the async thread
```

What seems to be happening is that as soon as the Python listener starts, the thread locks waiting for a connect. Control never seems to pass back to the main thread to allow the client to connect.

Appreciate any help I can get on this.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I am way outside my area of knowledge here, but as nobody answers in 10 hours, I will make an attempt.

I think the problem is that julia does not have an aggressive scheduler. You can use concurrency features, but they will be scheduled cooperatively in the same process. Since PyCall does not return or call a (julia?) sleep, the control will not return to the client. You might try addprocs or start julia with -p 2, but I'm not sure it will help.

See also http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/parallel-computing/ where this is much better explained.

Comment: Thanks, ivarne. I have tried using -p 2 but that doesn't seem to help. Will look at the docs more carefully.

Comment: you need to do `@everywhere using PyCall`, change the `@async` to `@spawnat 2 begin ...`, and put the `@pyimport` inside the spawnat block. i just tried it and it works fine then. or use Python's multiprocessing module (or possibly asynccore).